# SwiftUi button background color showing over text

Tags: swift, swiftui

For some reason my background showing over my text label. I have the background as white and text as red but for some reason the white background covers the text. I am referring to the tab me button. In preview is show correctly however in the stimulator it show with the issue.

`````
 VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                Text("Connection Pin:")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
                Button {
                    print("Button tapped!")
                } label: {
                    Text("Tap me")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .bold()
                }
                .background(Color.white)
}
````[![enter image description here][1]][1]


[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9dmT.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVOJc.png
`````

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine, I tested it and its showing how you want red text and white background, I am attaching an image on what I see in my simulator.[image]

Comment: It show correctly on iOS but when I run the same code on macOS it does not look that way. On macOS its showing the white background over the Text. I clean build folder then rebuild but for some reason on macOS it keeps putting all of my button text behind the white background